# Getting error .split("").reverse() not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    str = prompt("enter a string");
rev = str.split("").join("").reverse();
console.log(rev);
```

Guys, I am trying to reverse an array using the above code but I am getting an error stating "Type error .reverse() .split("") and .join("") is not a function.

Please help.

Comment: `str = prompt("enter a string");rev = str.split("").reverse().join("");console.log(rev);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript strings have no `reverse` function. You'll have to reverse the *array* before `join`ing it together into a string:

```js
const str = 'abcde';
const res = str.split('').reverse().join('');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `.split(“”)` does not occur in the OP’s code. If you’re referring to the title, that’s just the auto-formatting of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Xufox Lovely. A Q&A Site for Programming that auto-formats ASCII quotes into smart quotes, what could go wrong? :P

Comment: See [Double-quotes (“”) conversions in question titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297344/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox Thanks, I searched for some titles and realized it was probably being done automatically but I hadn't looked for a meta thread on it.

Answer (score 0):

`join` turns an array into a string, and `reverse` is not a function of a string. I think what you might have been going for is:

```
rev = str.split("").reverse().join("");
```

...which will reverse a string.